# Is it safe to unplug a iPad or iPhone without ejecting first?

Tags: iphone, ipad, catalina, charging

Should I eject the device first? Or can I just unplug my iPad or iPhone when I am done charging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is best practice?** It is always best to eject removable media (iDevice, external storage, etc.) before disconnecting it.

**Is is 'safe' if you don't eject first?** Mostly yes, but not guaranteed. As long as there isn't an active file transfer, or the device isn't otherwise being accessed by your computer, its pretty much fine to do. Though there is a chance for corruption, I don't think I've ever encountered it over the numerous times I've done it - accidentally or not.

Aside: last I checked, the most Apple USB buses supply a measly 0.5 amps, so you'll get much faster charging performance if you use the supplied power adapter with your device.

Answer (score -1):

I had an iPhone 6 until 3 days ago. I bought the iPhone 6 new when they were first introduced. I'm retired so I'm home a lot. Just about every day I would plug my iPhone into my charger in the morning and unplug it to take into the bedroom at night. I always just unplugged it so this process went on for over 3-4 years. Based on this I'd say it was safe to just unplug the phone.  I replaced my battery once when Apple had their universal battery replacement program a couple of years ago. I've never had trouble with the battery.

Maybe someone has a counterexample or some technical data to confirm my finding or to show otherwise.

Comment: I’m not sure this answers the question about connecting your iPhone to a computer since there’s no such equivalent eject (or which would even be necessary) for wall chargers.

Comment: There was no mention of connecting iPhone to a computer.

Comment: Talking “ejection” actually includes computers. There are no power plugs where you need to “eject” a device

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:catalina]

Comment: oh, so you think that means he's using his computer to charge his devices? Yea I think you are right.  I'll leave my answer because of the info which someone may find useful.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Why the downvote, The OP may decide to just use the charger!